# Converting Indices of Series to Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert the Indices of a Series `amounts` into its Columns. For example, I need to convert:

```
     1983-05-15      1
     1983-11-15      1
     1984-05-15      1
     1984-11-15     101
```

into:

```
     1983-05-15      1983-11-15      1984-05-15      1984-11-15
             1               1               1              101
```

I wasn't able to find any documentation on doing this for `Series` type Objects specifically and don't know how to do this.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a `DataFrame` out of your `Series`, then the `.T` property returns a transposed version.

```
In [87]: pd.DataFrame(s).T
Out[87]: 
   1983-05-15  1983-11-15  1984-05-15  1984-11-15
0           1           1           1         101
```

Comment: I was actually aware of that and hoping there might be another way, as I have several such `Series` Objects. Thank you anyway.

Comment: What are you trying to avoid?  No matter what your desired output is going to be a `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in method to convert a series to a dataframe, [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html#pandas.Series.to_frame):

```
In [146]:    
s.to_frame().T

Out[146]:
1983-05-15  1983-11-15  1984-05-15  1984-11-15
1                    1           1         101
```